# How to get next semicolon after a string?

Tags: c#, string, search

Suppose I have the below lines in a textbox:

```
   I am unable to
             find the next semicolon;
   I need your help;
```

There may or may not be `\n`.

I need to get the next semicolon i.e, `";"` after the string `"unable"`.

How do I go about it?

Comment: Have you looked at `string.IndexOf`? You'll want to use it twice... (or use a regular expression, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var idx = yourString.IndexOf("unable");
if (idx != -1)
{
    idx = yourString.IndexOf(';', idx);
    if (idx != -1)
    {
        // you found it
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xkyx09y(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution.. it worked as needed.. Now I need to get the text from unable (including unable) to semicolon. How to get that? Do i need to use substring()?

Comment: Maybe you should actually do some troubleshooting on your own.  What about the documentation is confusing exactly?

Answer (score -2):

Possible solution:

```
private const string UNABLE = "unable";
var index = yourTextBoxString.IndexOf(UNABLE);
if(index != -1)
{
    index = yourTextBoxString.IndexOf(";", index + UNABLE.Lengh)
    if(index != -1)
    //found it, do something
}
```

Comment: This is wrong.  `IndexOf(char,int)` returns the index in the original string, not the substring.

Comment: @Ed S Yes this is wrong but not the way you think it is. This just means he added the length of the word of "unable" to the index so that it will literally start after the word. Since index starts with 0 he should have deducted 1 to the length though

Comment: @TheProvost: You're right, not sure why I read that differently last night.

Comment: oh no why was this marked as answer. Ed answered it first and Ricky's answer has minor coding errors. Downvoting this answer.